# Want to access wins data in JSON body , can`t find the right path to the result?

Tags: node.js, json, curl, post, chainlink

I'm developing this external adapter for my Chainlink node. From RapidAPI I call a POST API call based on the name field. This is the returned body.

[image]
In node.js I will like to retrieve "wins" in "data" array:

```
>     Requester.request(options, customError)
>         .then(response => {
>          
>           response.data.result = Requester.validateResultNumber(response.data,['data', 'performance','wins'])
>           callback(response.status, Requester.success(jobRunID, response))
>         })
```

But I'm getting the :

> AdapterError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'wins' of undefined

What path do I need to write to get to my result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the path with : ["data", "0", "performance", "wins"].